# How to create own autogenerated files by composer

Tags: symfony, composer-php

I'm working on project in Symfony 2. In this project, there's file named `parameters.yml.dist` which is base for composer to create `parameters.yml`. We have two environments (prod, dev), each one has own parameters file (for dev it's `parameters_dev.yml`).

My problem is that, some users and servers have different dev configuration, but file exists in repository - that makes deployment and work a little bit uncomfortable.

Is there a way to make that `parameters_dev.yml` file be autogenerated same as parameters for prod? I tried to create this `*.dist` file but that's not worked, maybe I have to do something else?

Comment: Why and how is Composer involved in creating `parameters.yml`?

Comment: @Sven `composer install` creates this file. I'd like use the same mechanism for `parameters_dev.yml`. If it's managed by symfony, where?

Comment: `composer install` does not usually create such file. If it get's created, it is the work of either some plugin, or some script associated with installing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution. Parameters are managed by this bundle: https://github.com/Incenteev/ParameterHandler

That's how part of my `composer.json` file looks now:

```
"incenteev-parameters": [
    {
        "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
    },
    {
        "file": "app/config/parameters_dev.yml"
    }
],
```

Funny, I searched `composer.json` in first place but didn't found anything.